# UIImageView goes black inconsistently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView, contains some views in each cell, and one of the views is UIImageView.
In the cellForRow method I am loading the UIImageView with an image, but sometimes, the UIImageView just shows a black screen.

I thought it can be for two reasons - Corrupted UIImage or Memory problem.

The UIImage is not corrupted (It's the same UIImage all the time), and I even checked what is the behavior when I put a manually corrupted image -> It goes white! not black...

I check if I have some memory warnings, ViewDidUnload launch -> nothing. Even simulated memory warning in the simulator, and nothing, it has nothing to do with that.

Does someone have any clue why it's happening?

Thanks!

---

Here is my cellForRow method.
Basically, it's a list of cells with UIWebView and UIImageView on top, and when the table scrolls, I hide the webview and show the imageview, and vice versa. Maybe it has something to do with my problem, but I doubt it, cause the image is the same, and uiimagaview is not getting released.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {   
   ImMailMessage *message = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

ImFullMessageTableViewCell *cell = (ImFullMessageTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImFullMessageTableViewCell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImFullMessageTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.delegate = self;

    //add gestures
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellPinched:)] autorelease];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    pinchGesture.delegate = self;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellPanned:)] autorelease];
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
    panGesture.delegate = self;

}


cell.threadState = _state;
cell.mailMessage = message;


UIImage *image = [self imageForMailMessage:message];
if (!image)
{
    // if no image, put the webview and reload it.
    cell.webView.mailMessage = message;     
    cell.webViewImageView.hidden = YES;
    cell.webViewImageView.image = nil;
    [cell.webView reloadMailMessage];

}
else // image exists!
{
    cell.webViewImageView.image = image;

    // replace the web view with the recived image.
    [cell replaceWebViewWithImageView];
}


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your cellForRow code?

Comment: In order to better address your question we will need the code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: Hi, Added the cellForRow method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your "cellForRow", you first try to recycle old cells, then if none available you create a new one. You somehow get access to the UIImageView just after that (or you are using the one that the cell provides?)

The first thing I would do is in cellForRow don't even set an image - find the UIImageView, then either log it or assert() that its there, then set the background color to say green":

imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

If you see a bunch of green colored rectangles where your image is, then you can proceed to the next step (after removing that green background!), and set the image - but LOG each time the image is set, that is log the image before you set it, so you can be 100% sure that in fact you have a valid image.

If you get this far, you got the green, your logging your images, but it still isn't working then add a comment and I'll check back.

EDIT: So continue NOT writing an image - you should have a imageView now just drawing its background.

Add a delegate method: "- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
"

Put a log there and for each cell, log its index, the imageView, the imageView.backgroundColor, and imageView.image (should be nil!). I suspect you will find that the backgroundcolor is not green, or there is some image

Comment: Hi, first of all I've added the cellForRow method.
This is a custom cell, so it has a UIImageView of it's own.
I saw the green rects and the logs, but still, sometimes it looks black. don't why, very strange...

Comment: Fine - so even without setting an image, sometimes it is black. Well, that means that it has nothing to do with your image - I'll edit my answer now. So when you create a cell, you add a new UIImageCView, and when you get a recycled cell, you just retrieve the imageView from the cell contentView?

Comment: Ok, Found the problem! The problem was with the Image. I captured the webview underneath, but I did it sometimes when the webview was hidden. That's the problem! You actually led me to the solution by the tests I did. Thanks!